# How to add an image modifying the existing document Using FPDF-PHP?

Tags: php

I have a document in which I need to add the image in a specific location, hence how I can  achieve this using FPDF-PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$this->Cell($w[4],6,$this->Image('img/lp_ikona_up.png',$this->GetX(),$this->GetY()),'LR',0,'R');
```

Comment: @dj I need to modify the already existing PDF file. Which Is uploaded by User.. I Just need to modify the existing PDF, so could it be done using FPDF?